# Understanding varchar(max) 8000 column and why I can store more than 8000 characters in it

Tags: sql-server, varchar, max

From [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/char-and-varchar-transact-sql) Microsoft doc,+

> n defines the string length and can be a value from 1 through 8,000.
>   max indicates that the maximum storage size is 2^31-1 bytes (2 GB).
>   The storage size is the actual length of the data entered + 2 bytes.

Please help me understand this.

The max characters for varchar seems to be `8000`, which is way less than `2GB` worth of data.

I see that there are records in this `varchar(max)` column of a specific table that have `len(mycolumn)` > 100 000.
Thus I know I can get way more than `8000` characters into a `varchar(max)` column.

**Question 1:** How does the `8000` characters come into play and where should I be aware of it?

**Question 2** : will a .net datareader query to this column always return the full result with 100 000+ character?

Comment: Note that `varchar(max)` was once called `text` and was treated as a different data type.

Comment: Maybe read [this](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/whats-the-point-of-using-varcharn-anymore/)? Its **related** to 8K page sizes. Values too large to fit in a single page (the limit is actually slightly larger than 8000) are saved to LOB_DATA pages (Large OBject).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I can see why you're misunderstanding this - it's a little tricky. These are all valid:

- VARCHAR(1) - one character string
- VARCHAR(4000) - 4,000 characters
- VARCHAR(8000) - 8,000 characters - and if you use a number for this field's definition, that's the highest NUMBER you can use, but watch this:
- VARCHAR(MAX) - that one holds up to 2GB.

And yes, if you try to get data out of a VARCHAR(MAX) field, and somebody stored 2GB in there, buckle up.

Comment: `and somebody stored 2GB in there, buckle up.` - Been there with a few blob files

Answer (score 7):

> Question 1: How does the 8000 characters come into play and where
>   should I be aware of it?

Setting n to 8000 causes 8000 characters to come into play. You need to be aware of the [Precision, Scale, and Length (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/precision-scale-and-length-transact-sql) references about char, nchar, nvarchar, and varchar. In contrast, setting n to max (no quotes) causes SQL Server to store (and return) the maximum number of bytes (as mentioned in your quote).

> Question 2 : will a .net datareader query to this column always return
>   the full result with 100 000+ character?

This is a .Net (not a SQL Server) question, but the .Net datareader fetches a stream of bytes. A byte is not a character, and SQL Server returns bytes (not characters). If n is set to 8000 and the data type is nvarchar, SQL Server returns up to 8000 bytes, which the .Net datareader can interpret to be 4000 Unicode characters. If n is set to 8000 and the data type is varchar, SQL Server returns  up to 8000 bytes, which the .Net datareader can interpret to be up to 8000 ANSI characters. If n is set to max and the data type is nvarchar, SQL Server returns up to 2^31-1 bytes, which the .Net datareader can interpret to be up to (2^31-1)/2 characters. If n is set to max and the data type is varchar, SQL Server returns up to 2^31-1 bytes, which the .Net datareader can interpret to be up to 2^31-1 ANSI characters.

If you choose use char or varchar (instead of nchar or nvarchar) because they can store more "characters" (more accurately: bytes), you need to be aware that many Unicode characters have no equivalent ANSI character (thus a large portion of our world's users will be unable to see their localized/native characters in your app).